# parsing data from log into json file

Tags: python, json

I have a log file in such format,

```
{
  "box1" : {
    "item1" : "testValue1",
    "item2" : "testValue2"
  },
  "foods" : [
    {
      "orange" : "per pound",
      "price" : 2.99
    },
    {
      "rice" : "in bag",
      "price" : 1.99
      "extra-key" : "extra-Value",
      "extra-key2" : "extra-Value2",
    },
    {
      "beer" : "in box",
      "price" : 12.99
      "extra-key3" : "extra-Value3"
      "content" : None
    }
 ]
}
```

and I want to extract following values into an output file in python:

```
[ "orange" : "per pound", "rice" : "in bag","beer" : "in box" ]
```

Can someone show me how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

For reading json files, you can use a Python module - [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). It reads a file and returns a corresponding data structure stored in a file.

Since you have a dictionary, you can easily access values simply by indexing the dictionary.

```
import json

with open('logFileName') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Foods is a list of dictionaries, so you have to access it like that
print data['foods'][0]['orange']
```

Note that you have incorrectly specified the desired output format because you're mixing list and dictionary syntax. I assume that you, in fact, wanted to extract a dictionary out of the log.

This is a problem if you don't know in advance what type of food will be in a list because it's not easy to determine which key in a dictionary is food (e.g. `rice`), and which is something completely different, for example `extra-key`.

For a quick introduction to Python, read [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).